# services display for search index based view

Tags: services, search, views

I am building a search page using view. the view get results from search index created and have indexed nodes and it works fine and display results as expected

the problem comes when trying to add services display for the same view it only display as in the picture [image]

please help to make services display from views based on search api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the "block" display on your view instead of "services" display to avoid this issue as the views has many issues with search api and [services views](https://www.drupal.org/project/services_views)